# Wicket user confirmation and busy indicator

Tags: ajax, wicket

I am trying to implement the Javascript / Wicket 6.x user confirmation solution described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Getting+user+confirmation).

It works ok BUT I can't figure out how to execute the Javascript that hides my busy indicator if the user clicks Cancel (script returns `false`).

From [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/ajax.html#ajax_5) :

> getPrecondition(Component): returns the JavaScript code that will be
>   used as precondition for the AJAX call. If the script returns false
>   then neither the Ajax call **nor the other handlers will be
>   executed**.

If I am using

`ajaxCallListener.onPrecondition( "return confirm('" + text + "');" );`

it means that I can't invoke any further Javascript if the confirmation returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your busy indicator in `ajaxCallListener.onBeforeSend("...")` callback. It is executed only if all preconditions pass. I.e. if the user presses 'Cancel' then there won't be busy indicator being shown at all, so nothing to hide.